# How can I update my cart using js/ajax when the billing state or country is changed in woocommerce checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I have a single page checkout and used this code but the cart is not getting updated.
I am also having ajax auto update cart plugin and according to its docs. if I add the qty class to the select field it should update cart automatically.But it didnt.
Can anyone help??

I used this code in the child themes function.php

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'billing_country_update_checkout', 50);
function billing_country_update_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
          jQuery('select#billing_state, select#billing_country').change(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById("billing_country");
        element.classList.add("qty");
         console.log('Event: Page is reloaded');
  });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Woocommerce have some js triggers for this situation :

**Woocommerce Checkout JS events :**

```
$( document.body ).trigger( 'init_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'payment_method_selected' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'updated_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'checkout_error' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'applied_coupon_in_checkout' );
$( document.body ).trigger( 'removed_coupon_in_checkout' );
```

For your task need use event $( document.body ).trigger( 'update_checkout' );

Changed code :

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'billing_country_update_checkout', 50);
function billing_country_update_checkout() {
    if ( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
          jQuery('select#billing_state, select#billing_country').change(function() {
                    var element = document.getElementById("billing_country");
                    element.classList.add("qty");
                    console.log('Event: Page is reloaded');
                    
                    jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

If you wanna use the result:

```
jQuery('body').on('updated_checkout', function(event, json, string){
            
     console.log(json.fragments);
});
```

json.fragments consist the checkout page after update

Comment: This is not updating the cart though.

Comment: Is there any other method we can use to update the cart when billing state or country is changed?? without using plugin?

Comment: @Anurag it's an original method by woocommerce. If it isn't updating, need to check the code of your checkout form, need to check your ajax request in the inspector of browser etc. Your description in question isn't enough

Comment: I have used single page checkout where the cart and checkout page is the same. Can it cause any issue??

Comment: And the checkout form code is the default one

Comment: This object gets loaded as well

.woocommerce-checkout-payment: "\n<div id=\"payment\" class=\"woocommerce-checkou
.woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table: "<table class=\"shop_table woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table\">\n\t<thead>\n\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t<th class=\"

Comment: @Anurag it isn't enough. In woocommerce the checkout and the cart are clearly defined. Maybe you use the specific plugins for the checkout page. Need more the description your problem

Comment: @Anurag If plugin is not built following woocommerce dev standarts or its using own js feel free to contact your plugin dev.